# Cannot build ARCore in Unity 2018.1b

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I got the following error: `BuildHelper.cs(34,18): error CS0535: GoogleARCoreInternal.BuildHelper does not implement interface member UnityEditor.Build.IPreprocessBuild.OnPreprocessBuild(UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)`

I understand Unity 2018.1 is beta at the moment, but [this article](https://www.andreasjakl.com/remote-arcore-unitys-experimental-arinterface/) claims they managed to do it:

> I’m using Unity 2018.1 Beta 6. All versions starting with Unity
>   2017.3.0f3 are compatible.

Comment: I think will be better if you'll ask unity's supports, they're answer really fast and can help. "Help - Report a bug".

Answer (score 0):

Unity has really changed interface from version 2017.3:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuild.OnPreprocessBuild.html

to version 2018.1b

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuild.OnPreprocessBuild.html

Now it is probably up to google ARCore guys how to cope with this situation inside of ARCore sdk.

Comment: You file for a bug request on ARCore's Github page to let them know about this update.